# React-Native Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'

Tags: compiler-errors, react-native

My problem is: I formatting my computer and installed the react-native following this guide 'Getting Started'. But when i do npx react-native run-android i get this following error:

https://pastebin.com/ben4AE9u

i try:
`cd android && gradlew clean` and i got a new error similar.

`npx react-native init abc --version 0.60.1` and the error persist.

`delete C:\Users\ABC\.android` and still with error.

I just don't know what to do anymore.
I thank anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `google()` at first place in your repositories of `build.gradle`.